# Subtract TotalExpense from BudgetAmount In Budget Table for a specific date

Tags: sql-server

I have a `Budget` table which has the following columns:

```
BudgetId, BudgetDate, BudgetAmount
```

and a table `Expense` which has the following columns:

```
ExpenseID, Date, ExDescrip, Category_fk, ExAMount
```

How can I subtract daily expense from the budget of a sepecific date?

I am using this query to get the sum of the expenses. This query is ok to give the total expense of that date from budget.

```
select sum(ExMount) as totalExpense
from Budget b, Expense ex
where b.BudgetDate=ex.Date
```

Now, how can I subtract totalExpense from the BudgetAmount from the budget table?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Budget]
( [BudgetId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
  [BudgetDate] [date] NULL, 
  [BudgetAmount] [int] NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Budget] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [BudgetId] ASC )
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] 
) ON [PRIMARY] 
GO
```

The script of Expense table is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Expense](
    [ExpenseID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [date] NULL,
    [ExDescrip] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Category_fk] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ExMount] [int] NULL,
    [BudgetFk] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Expense] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ExpenseID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: I take it there can be many rows per date in `Expense`, correct? Can there also be many rows per date in `Budget`?

Answer (score 1):

To start with, `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`

```
select
    b.BudgetDate,
    sum(b.BudgetAmount) - coalesce(sum(ex.ExMount),0) as BudgetLessExpenses
from dbo.Budget b
left join dbo.Expense ex
on b.BudgetDate=ex.Date
group by b.BudgetDate
```

BTW. Shouldn't there be a `UNIQUE` constraint on `[Budget].[BudgetDate]` ?

Comment: Check column names, `[ExMount] [int] NULL,` particulary, I used the names from table definitions in your post.

Comment: names are same dont know why it  is saying that multi-part identifier could not  found. (Invalid object name Budget ) how it can be possible ?? I have the same table name